# How to hide items in spinner? I set 3 items(Home, Work, Custom) in spinner

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi,

How to hide items in spinner? I set 3 items(Home, Work, Custom) in 
 spinner by using string array. when i click spinner in first time display all 3 
 items , I pick one item in that time(example home). next time I click spinner 
 only 2 items will display (example work, custom)I pick one item (example work). 
 third time i click spinner only one item will display (example custom). how to 
 i do it ?I attached my screenshot below.
         [image][image]

Comment: are you transitioning in a new activity? or using the same activity?

Comment: select the spinner item and drag the address then save. this address display in new activity.

Comment: @Dora did you mean that if i select item1 from list of 3 items, after item1 would be hide from the list?

Answer (score 2):

try this one:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
    // remove items in your array that you are using in your spinner 
    myArrayList.remove("Home");
    //update your adapter
    adapterSpinner.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
    // your code here
}
```

});

Comment: This page is my second activity. when i save the title(spinner selected items)and address. this is display in my first activity.

Comment: @Dora please specify what u want to say. It hard to get your point

Comment: i'd also do it this way

Comment: wait i will explain. i attched my screenshot and explain it. now how to add screenshot in this page. i mean in slackoverflow

Comment: isn't the code not readable for you? when the user selects an item from the spinner it removes an item on the current arraylist and update it using the `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Comment: i have 2 activity one is fav_add and fav_list. In fav_add page, i add title (selected spinner item, address). In fav_list page, display title and address will be display in listview. In my doubt --->>> I select titlle (home or custom or work) i pick one item to save the address that address with title will display fav_list page . next time i  go to the fav_add page , in spinner which i tems previously selected that time can't display.